# getting garbage using SendMessage to populate a Listbox

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, listbox, sendmessage

I'm trying to populate a Listbox using c++ on Visual Studio. I have an array of std:string and i want to use them. My solution doesn't seem to work:

```
std::string label = "something";
char *buffer;
buffer = _strdup((label).c_str());
```

I checked and the buffer variable contains the correct string, but then i call SendMessage

```
SendMessage(hwndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)buffer);
```

The ListBox gets populated, but instead of "something" i see some random japanese characters...

Comment: What happens if you use `SendMessageA` instead of `SendMessage`?

Comment: it works!! I need to investigate on this...thanks!!

Comment: The code segment has a memory leak from `_strdup`, sorry if it's just the sample code.  Also there is no need for the  `_strdup` call.

Comment: visual studio complained that "Error C4996 'strdup': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _strdup". About the memory leak, you are right, i'm fixing it :)

Comment: Ignore the compiler warning about `strdup` there's no need for it in the first place. `SendMessageA(hwndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)(label.c_str()));` will work just as well, with no need to allocate more memory.

Comment: Long-term, you should switch from `std::string` and `char` to `std::wstring` and `wchar_t`. This will bring your application into the 20th century with Unicode support, and allow you to call `SendMessageW`, as you should be.

Comment: thanks to both, i'll try to bring my application into the 20th century (not even 21st? :P)

Comment: @CodyGray Note that your advice conflicts with many people who say you should use UTF-8 everywhere (which means converting to UTF-16 immediately before calling SendMessage).

Comment: @immibis: Looking at this question alone, does UTF-8 really get you closer to a solution? Being dogmatic is wrong. It gets worse when being dogmatic makes a problem more complex. Advice needs rationale, so that you know when good advice turns bad. *"Many people [...] say"* isn't.

Comment: @immibis Yes, I'm aware of those people. I disagree with them. I've grown rather tired of making the argument. As far as I'm concerned, all UI code should use whatever the operating system does. In Windows, that means UTF-16. The "UTF-8 Everywhere" campaign is rather stupid, it doesn't make sense to use anything "everywhere". Use UTF-8 as part of your public-facing API, and when sharing data with the world, but when interfacing with the OS, use what the OS does. Doing the conversion immediately before SendMessage can't make sense; UI strings should have never gotten converted to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SendMessage` is a macro and it may be defined to `SendMessageW`, which uses Unicode string.

You are using `std::string` and `char`, so try using `SendMessageA`, which uses ANSI strings, explicitly.